# How can i change the date Format on the top of the react-big-calender

Tags: reactjs, react-big-calendar

I have used react-big-calender in my project now i used only day view of that and want to customise the date format as per my need it currently shows as wednesday Sep 2 and what i want is 2 September 2020 and i didn't find any props to manipulate that any help would be great help my code is as below

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Calendar, momentLocalizer } from 'react-big-calendar';
import moment from 'moment';
import withDragAndDrop from 'react-big-calendar/lib/addons/dragAndDrop';
import { Box } from './styled';
import 'react-big-calendar/lib/addons/dragAndDrop/styles.css';
import 'react-big-calendar/lib/css/react-big-calendar.css';
import { changeAppointment } from '../api';

export default function Calender(props) {
    const { date } = props;
    const { data } = props;
    const localizer = momentLocalizer(moment);
    const DnDCalendar = withDragAndDrop(Calendar);
    const [events, setEvents] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        let tempEvents = [];
        data.forEach((element) => {
            const data = {
                title: element.patient.name + ', ' + element.patient.phone,
                id: element.id,
                start: moment.utc(element.datetime).toDate(),
                end: moment.utc(element.datetime).add(30, 'minutes').toDate(),
            };
            tempEvents.push(data);
            setEvents(tempEvents);
        });
    }, [data]);

    const onEventResize = (data) => {
        const { start, end, event } = data;
        const newEvents = [...events];
        newEvents.forEach((existingEvent) => {
            if (existingEvent.id === event.id) {
                existingEvent.start = start;
                existingEvent.end = end;
                const info = {
                    id: event.id,
                    datetime: moment.utc(start).format(),
                };
                changeAppointment(info)
                    .then((info) => {
                        console.log(info, "infoo")
                    }).catch((err) => {
                        console.log(err,"error")
                    })
            }
        });
        setEvents(newEvents);
    };

    return (
        <Box>
            <DnDCalendar
                localizer={localizer}
                defaultDate={date}
                defaultView="day"
                timeslots={1}
                view={'day'}
                views={{
                    day: true,
                }}
                min={new Date(0, 0, 0, 9, 0, 0)}
                max={new Date(0, 0, 0, 23, 30, 0)}
                events={events}
                localizer={localizer}
                onEventDrop={onEventResize}
                onEventResize={onEventResize}
                resizable
                step={30}
                selectable={true}
            />
        </Box>
    );
}
```

and i have attached an file to show which date i am talking about[image]

Comment: your code helped to fix start and end time of calender. I will like to know that i want to restrict this start and end date to UK time 8AM and 6PM at evening how can i ensure it will work fine?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this use the `formats` prop. It has multiple options for formatting the date display, dependent upon which `View` your currently viewing.

http://jquense.github.io/react-big-calendar/examples/index.html#prop-formats

```js
let formats = {
  dateFormat: 'dd',

  dayFormat: (date, culture, localizer) =>
    localizer.format(date, 'DDD', culture),

  dayRangeHeaderFormat: ({ start, end }, culture, localizer) =>
    localizer.format(start, { date: 'short' }, culture) + ' — ' +
    localizer.format(end, { date: 'short' }, culture)
}

<Calendar formats={formats} />
```

Most take the `(date: Date, culture: ?string, localizer: Object) => string` method signature, unless they deal with range, and use whichever `localizer` you configured for your instance. So, for you (use seem to be using Moment), it would be something like:

```js
const dayFormat = (date, culture, localizer) => localizer.format(date, 'D MMMM YYYY', culture);

return (
  <Calendar
    // other props
    formats={{
      dayFormat
    }}
  />
```

Comment: thanks mate it works fine thanks for the explanation very well ;)